# Unable to find function in workspace

Tags: r

I used `lapply` to run a function 100 times with below argument:

```
lapply(1:100, myfunc)
```

but I got this error message:

```
error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'myfunc' not found
```

I used `list.files()` to check that if function is in working directory and it was there. So I don't know why I got this message.

Comment: `list.files` shows you what's in your `OS`.   You want the function to be in `R`.

Comment: When I run "lapply" the function should be in working directory. Is that right?

Comment: Nope ;)    Have a look at @joran's answer.  He tells you how to go about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds vaguely like you're expecting R to behave like Matlab (based on my hazy memories of Matlab).

Just because a file containing a function is in your working directory does not mean anything about whether R knows about it. You need to `source()` the file containing the function, and then verify that the function exists in your workspace using `ls()`.

So for example, if the file containing the function is in `"foo/bar/myfile.R"` then I'd run:

```
source("foo/bar/myfile.R")
```

and the verify that the function is in my *workspace* by running `ls()`.

Comment: I would not have made the matlab connection.

Comment: ... or maybe Octave? No reason to assume OP is a chump. :)